# LINQ to XML Newbie: Moving Nodes From One Node To Another

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Greetings!

I have an XElement object that contains the following:

```
<Root>
    <SubSections>
        <SubSection id="A">
            <Foo id="1">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
            <Foo id="2">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
            <Foo id="3">
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
        </SubSection>
        <SubSection id="B">
            <Foo id="4">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
            <Foo id="5">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
         </SubSection>
        <SubSection id="C">

        </SubSection>
    </SubSections>
</Root>
```

I'd like to move Foo's 2 and 3 to the SubSection with the id of "C" such that the result is:

```
<Root>
    <SubSections>
        <SubSection id="A">
            <Foo id="1">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
        </SubSection>
        <SubSection id="B">
            <Foo id="4">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
            <Foo id="5">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
        </SubSection>
        <SubSection id="C">
            <Foo id="2">
                <Bar />
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
            <Foo id="3">
                <Bar />
            </Foo>
        </SubSection>
    </SubSections>
</Root>
```

What's the best way to go about moving Foo sections "2" and "3" to the "C" SubSection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get Foo sections 2 and 3 with a query like:

```
var foos = from xelem in root.Descendants("Foo")
           where xelem.Attribute("id").Value == "2" || xelem.Attribute("id").Value == "3"
           select xelem;
```

And then iterate that list and remove them from their parents with

```
xelem.Remove();
```

Then just add them to the correct node with:

```
parentElem.Add(xelem);
```

The first query will get you both sections then remove and add each one to the correct place on the tree.

Here's a complete solution:

```
var foos = (from xElem in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Foo")
                   where xElem.Attribute("id").Value == "2" || xElem.Attribute("id").Value == "3"
                   select xElem).ToList();

        var newParentElem = (from xElem in xDoc.Root.Descendants("SubSection")
                            where xElem.Attribute("id").Value == "C"
                            select xElem).Single();

        foreach(var xElem in foos)
        {
            xElem.Remove();
            newParentElem.Add(xElem);
        }
```

After that your xDoc should have the correct tree.

Comment: A few minor comments: .Value is a string so quote the "2" and "3".  I believe you can just call foos.Remove() instead of iterating.  Though you may need to copy the foos before then since .Remove() cleans foos up.

Comment: You are probably right.  I imagine you could probably just call foos.Remove() followed by parentElem.Add(foos) but I figured it'd be better to iterate and then you can remove and then add that element, and then move the IEnumerable to the next element.

Comment: This results in an empty parentElem node:

var toMove = foos;
foos.Remove();
parentElem.Add(toMove);

And this kills the web server (probably because it keeps adding and removing the same node over and over):

var toMove = foos;
parentElem.Add(toMove);
foos.Remove();

Any ideas?

Comment: Iterating is probably safer, but I find it a challenge to never write a foreach statement again. :)  Instead of the loop, try: newParentElem.Add(foos); foos.Remove();