# Moving node in xdocument

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to find a node by the attribute and move it to bottom.

```
XNode node = doc.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "123").FirstOrDefault();
if (node != null)
{
    node.Root.Elements().Where(s => e.Attribute("id").Value == "123").Remove();
    doc.Root.Add(node);
}
```

This does not always work.  on the .Remove() line, I sometimes get a nullReferenceException. So I guess this means that it matched and got a node on the FirstOrDefault(), but then same exact linq query two lines later didn't match anything.  Not seeing how this is possible.  Am I missing something?  There's nothing concurrently touching this document or anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to XML Newbie: Moving Nodes From One Node To Another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927350/linq-to-xml-newbie-moving-nodes-from-one-node-to-another)

Comment: figured it out, there were some nodes where the id attribute didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927350/linq-to-xml-newbie-moving-nodes-from-one-node-to-another):

```
 var foos = (from xElem in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Foo")
                       where xElem.Attribute("id").Value == "2" || xElem.Attribute("id").Value == "3"
                       select xElem).ToList();

            var newParentElem = (from xElem in xDoc.Root.Descendants("SubSection")
                                where xElem.Attribute("id").Value == "C"
                                select xElem).Single();

            foreach(var xElem in foos)
            {
                xElem.Remove();
                newParentElem.Add(xElem);
            }
```

Comment: fair enough, but my problem is much simpler then that.  i want to move a node to the bottom within the same parent node.  why doesn't my code work?

Comment: actually, what i'm doing is identical to that, except i am using singleordefault() instead of single and then checking for a null case because in my case the node may not exist